# mysql constraints error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am building a jsp project and i have made a database for it which contains several tables and foreign keys in it. 
and i have made a simple page to insert some entities in my table but i got this error. I am working with jsp since a week,  i had inserted entities in my database table earlier but never got this error,  i have searched alot about this but still webbed in this error.  Pls help me with this   and tell me where i am going wrong.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Add Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <%@include file="header.jsp" %>

          <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">        
        <form action="saveTest.jsp">

                                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-2">
                                            <h3>Test Title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <h3><input type="text" class="form-control" name="test" required></h3>
                    </div>

                </div>

                                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-2">
                                            <h3>Description</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <h3><textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="des"></textarea></h3>
                    </div>

                </div>



                                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-6 col-lg-2">
                                            <h3><input type="submit" value="Add Test" class="form-control" ></h3>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </form>
                  </div>
          </div>
       <%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
    </body>
</html>
```

below is the page where query is:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Save Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        String test=request.getParameter("test");
        String des=request.getParameter("des");

         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/exam","root","password");
        String q="insert into test(testname,description) values(?,?);";
        PreparedStatement p=con.prepareStatement(q);
        p.setString(1, test);
        p.setString(2, des);
        p.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
        response.sendRedirect("addQuestion.jsp");
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the error i am getting is:

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`exam`.`test`, CONSTRAINT `testteacherid` FOREIGN KEY (`teacherid`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`teacherid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

type Exception report

message javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`exam`.`test`, CONSTRAINT `testteacherid` FOREIGN KEY (`teacherid`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`teacherid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`exam`.`test`, CONSTRAINT `testteacherid` FOREIGN KEY (`teacherid`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`teacherid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:555)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`exam`.`test`, CONSTRAINT `testteacherid` FOREIGN KEY (`teacherid`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`teacherid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
    org.apache.jsp.saveTest_jsp._jspService(saveTest_jsp.java:151)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`exam`.`test`, CONSTRAINT `testteacherid` FOREIGN KEY (`teacherid`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`teacherid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.ja
```

Comment: read messages, few database problems (columns, tables), we cannot say withou functional java code and database structure

Comment: It looks like you are trying to insert a test and the teacher does not exist in the db.

Comment: i have edited the question and added the query page in it.

Comment: In your 'test' table, do you have a column called 'teacherid' ? Is there a 'NOT NULL' constraint on the this column ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straight forward. its giving constraint violation error. This usually happens only if child table is inserting a value in a column which have foreign key relation and referencing foreign Table doesn't have this value.

column "testteacherid" should have one of the value from "teacherid" column of table "teacher".

"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`exam`.`test`, CONSTRAINT `testteacherid` FOREIGN KEY (`teacherid`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`teacherid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)".

its issue not with your code, it's about data values you are trying to insert.
parent table must have values which child table is referencing.

If you will give both table values and new values you want to insert, we can point out error in insert value.